# DateTime Difference is not working in Flutter Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to implement a solution to a flutter project where the user selects their Date of Birth from a DateTime picker and then a calculation is done to tell how old the user is. I need it to be able to tell if the user is older than 13 years of age. I am new to Flutter but from what I see the code should execute but currently it just stays at the original value of 0.0. What am I doing wrong?

```
 class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  DateTime _date = new DateTime.now();
  double differenceInYears = 0;

  Future<Null> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime dob = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: _date,
      firstDate: DateTime(1940),
      lastDate: _date,
    );
    Duration dur = _date.difference(dob);
    double differenceInYears = (dur.inDays / 365);
    print('$differenceInYears');
    setState(() {
      return differenceInYears;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text('$differenceInYears'),
            new RaisedButton(
              child: new Text('Selected Date'),
              onPressed: () {
                _selectDate(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you set the `differenceInYears` identifier in the `setState` method? Why are you returning it in the `setState` method in the `_selectDate` method? It would be great if you can create a dartpad for this

Comment: @sudo_kaizen Can you provide an example of what you are suggesting? If I am understanding your question correctly, I tried it but I was still not successful. As I said, I am new to Flutter/Dart so there is a strong possibility that I did it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  DateTime _date = new DateTime.now();
  double differenceInYears = 0;

  Future<Null> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime dob = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: _date,
      firstDate: DateTime(1940),
      lastDate: _date,
    );
    Duration dur = _date.difference(dob);
    // make the change here
    setState(() {
      differenceInYears = (dur.inDays / 365);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Text('$differenceInYears'),
            new RaisedButton(
              child: new Text('Selected Date'),
              onPressed: () {
                _selectDate(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

In the code listing you provided in your question, you are returning an identifier in the `setState` method. You are not supposed to do that. You should use the `setState` to set the state and not return an identifier

Comment: Thank you Sudo. I see what you are saying now.